# SQL Data Warehouse, Python, and SPROCs

Tags: python, sql, azure-sql-database

I have a dependency chain that I run nightly inside a Python script.  Part of this dependency chain is loading and transforming data via SPROCs on a MS SQL Server.  Our company just migrated our DB to Azure's SQL Data Warehouse, so I began to convert the dependency chain, but am now faced with an error that I assume is uniquely ADW-related when trying to run SPROCs we added to the server.  I have no issue executing the SPROC in SSMS, but the following code produced the subsequent error:

```
import pyodbc

def conn_string_AZUREDW():

    Uid = '***'
    Pwd = '***'

    driver = '{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}'
    server = 'ourServer'
    database = 'ourDB'

    conn_string = 'driver=%s; server=%s; database=%s; Uid=%s; Pwd=%s;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30' % (driver, server, database, Uid, Pwd)
    return str(conn_string)  

connObjectADW = conn_string_AZUREDW()
connADW = pyodbc.connect(connObjectADW)
cursorADW = connADW.cursor()

cursorADW.execute('exec [schema].[sproc]')
connADW.commit()
```

Error:

```
ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]111212;Operation cannot be performed within a transaction. (111212) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Example of SPROC:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROC [schema].[sproc] AS
BEGIN

    [DROP TEMP TABLE IF OBJECT EXISTS]
    [SELECT INTO TEMP TABLE]

    [DROP REAL TABLE IF OBJECT EXISTS]
    [SELECT INTO REAL TABLE]

END
GO
```

Has anyone had luck executing SPROCs from Python on Azure's SQL Data Warehouse?

Comment: Can you provide sql scirpt of the proc? Do you have "Begin Transaction" which is handled correctly?

Comment: Added to the above.  Let me know if that is not enough of the "form" SPROC.